# Xslt Nested For-Loop with break

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

All,

I'm new to XSLT and facing a typical problem. Below is the problem details

Based on the data below, i needed to show ItemA/ANum element only when its of AName BBC and not part of ItemB/tempBNum

So desired result for the below data should be 0214,BBC, since its part of the ItemA, also is a BBC is does not appear in ItemB.

```
<myData>
<ItemA>
    <ANum>0213</ANum>
    <AName>OOC</AName>
</ItemA>
<ItemA>
    <ANum>0031</ANum>
    <AName>BBC</AName>
</ItemA>
<ItemA>
    <ANum>0214</ANum>
    <AName>BBC</AName>
</ItemA>
<ItemA>
    <ANum>0044</ANum>
    <AName>BBC</AName>
</ItemA>

<ItemB>
    <tempBNum>0031</tempBNum>
</ItemB>
<ItemB>
    <tempBNum>0044</tempBNum>
</ItemB>
</myData>
```

For this end, I tried putting in a logic of having Nested For Loops, only problem being nested loop should break when ItemAObj/ANum = tempBNum, but its not breaking and producing duplicate results.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="myData/ItemA">
    <xsl:variable name="ItemAObj" select="." />
    Num = <xsl:value-of select="$ItemAObj/ANum"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/myData/ItemB">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ItemAObj/ANum!=tempBNum and $ItemAObj/AName='BBC'"> <xsl:value-of select="tempBNum"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use any `xsl:for-each` to solve the problem, much more you don't need *nested* `xsl:for-each`.

**In fact, the wanted `ItemA` elements can be selected with a single XPath expression**:

```
/*/ItemA[AName = 'BBC' 
       and 
         not(ANum = /*/ItemB/tempBNum)
        ]
```

Therefore a simple XSLT transformation that evaluates the above XPath expression and copies the result to the output is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/ItemA[AName = 'BBC' and not(ANum = /*/ItemB/tempBNum)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<myData>
    <ItemA>
        <ANum>0213</ANum>
        <AName>OOC</AName>
    </ItemA>
    <ItemA>
        <ANum>0031</ANum>
        <AName>BBC</AName>
    </ItemA>
    <ItemA>
        <ANum>0214</ANum>
        <AName>BBC</AName>
    </ItemA>
    <ItemA>
        <ANum>0044</ANum>
        <AName>BBC</AName>
    </ItemA>
    <ItemB>
        <tempBNum>0031</tempBNum>
    </ItemB>
    <ItemB>
        <tempBNum>0044</tempBNum>
    </ItemB>
</myData>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ItemA>
   <ANum>0214</ANum>
   <AName>BBC</AName>
</ItemA>
```

If we want just the values of the text nodes, just use the `string()` function:

```
string(/*/ItemA[AName = 'BBC' and not(ANum = /*/ItemB/tempBNum)])
```

Then the so modified transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "string(/*/ItemA[AName = 'BBC' and not(ANum = /*/ItemB/tempBNum)])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied on the same XML document (above), produces:

```
    0214
    BBC
```

**Note**: If performance starts to matter, using keys could be the next step to increase the efficiency of the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break, but you add the condition to make sure for no `previous-sibling` `ItemAObj/ANum = tempBNum`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in a different way, with the need for the **for-each** to iterate over the items and checking it one on turn. Instead, you could make use of a key to look up whether the **ItemB** elements exist for a number

```
<xsl:key name="itemB" match="ItemB" use="tempBNum" />
```

Then you can simply match **itemA** elements where there are no **ItemB** elements present for the **ANNum**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ItemA[AName='BBC'][not(key('itemB', ANum))]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="itemB" match="ItemB" use="tempBNum" />

   <xsl:template match="/myData">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ItemA[AName='BBC'][not(key('itemB', ANum))]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<ItemA>
   <ANum>0214</ANum>
   <AName>BBC</AName>
</ItemA>
```